# Can I transfer games from my friends steam account to mine?

Tags: steam

I bought Garry's Mod, and it's currently a 2 gb download.
I have poor wifi, so I want to know if I can transfer Gmod from my friend's account to mine. He has Gmod on Steam as well. Is it possible with the backup and restore method and a pen drive?

Comment: ok thanks, but gmod is a paid game. u sure it will work? of course , i also bought gmod, i just dont have the wifi to download it.so, a final time, will it work?

Comment: I don't see any reason it wouldn't work. It is basically a transfer between two libraries. That one is yours and the other your friend's doesn't matter.

Comment: [Check this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31453/is-it-possible-to-transfer-steam-games-from-one-pc-to-another?rq=1) if you're still unsure.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do the backup of the game and then restore it on to your machine via the Steam UI.

I have successfully done it by just copying the folder that contains the game and transferring that via USB drive. Probably quicker, but it will have to verify the files when you try and 'install' it on your computer, but that is usually a quick process if his game files are up to date.