# Can I bulk download Steam games?

Tags: steam

I have a substantial Steam library, and a new computer with plenty of disk space. I want to queue up all (or most) of my Steam games for downloading.

I know I can click on each one in turn, but I have to click a few times and wait while Steam creates locale game cache files.

Is there a way to do this quickly, preferably in bulk?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I move Steam games to a new computer without re-downloading them?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12695/how-do-i-move-steam-games-to-a-new-computer-without-re-downloading-them)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Steam has recently introduced an option to queue up games to be installed through a web interface. Make sure the target PC is running the Steam client, then go to your games list on the Steam website (the easiest way to do this is to click Community -> Profiles -> Games in the Steam client), open the All Games tab and click the install button next to the games you want to have installed. If not all of your games are showing up, click on Per page: All at the bottom of the page.

This is massively faster than going through the usual install dialog.

Comment: Hmm if you can do it through the browser you can automate it through the browser... unless Valve put in some throttling stuff.

Comment: Show all, then `jQuery('.clientConnItemIcon').click()`. For some reason, a few were missed. I reloaded the page and repeated a couple of times. This will also pause the currently downloading title, but is a lot better than manually installing 300 games.

Answer (score 11):

I assume its possible if you use the Steam browser protocol in a Batch (even even python) script.

here is a list of the possible commands, 
http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_browser_protocol

so you should need some thing like `steam://install/<id>` in a loop replacing the  with the id of those games in your library.
im not sure where you can get a list of game ID's you own.

who knows, maybe its even possible to just loop from 0 to 100000000, thus selecting every game you have on the way!

if you use this system id love to see your script!

Comment: hmm, that would be an interesting option

Comment: Unfortunately, even if scripted, the steam://install link requires user interaction (clicking "Next", ugh) to proceed with the installation.  Furthermore, I don't believe the script would have any way of knowing when a game installation completed, so as to start the next installation.

Comment: This used to work and you'd only have to click "next" once, like when you buy multiple games. http://www.stevether.711clan.net/steamgames/ I guess `subscriptioninstall` doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I'm aware, there is no way to queue the downloads in the way you want. If you still have your old computer, the easiest way to approximate this is to make a backup of your steamapps folder and re-install all your games from there, bypassing the need to re-download them. I suppose you could also transfer them from the old computer to the new one over a LAN, but I'd imagine most USB transfers would be faster.

Relevant forum post:

http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1251492

Answer (score 6):

as of August 2014 you can now shift+click all games in your library and right click to install. this will cue up all the games and download them all one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the very late reply, but a lot of people visit this page because they are searching for the same. This is exactly what you are looking for:

http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/171425.html (old link: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/171425)

IT IS FINALLY HERE!
This script allows you to install all your STEAM games without user intervention.

Made by the one and only real Master-Guy
http://steamcommunity.com/id/Master-Guy/games?tab=all
How it works:

1) Log in into Steam on the computer where you want to download the games.

2) Install this script on any computer, it may be the same one, or a different one. I used the same computer myself.

3) Log in into the Steam Community in FireFox

4) Go to the following URL in FireFox, but replace the asterix (*) with your Steam Community name: http://steamcommunity.com/id/*/games?tab=all#installall

For example:
http://steamcommunity.com/id/Master-Guy/games?tab=all#installall

The script will wait 5 seconds before starting, and will trigger all game installation with 10 second intervals.
The build-in download scheduler of Steam will pause the updates while starting the new one, and will only download one at a time.
This is to optimize your download speed.
This installed  around 400 games and 150 DLC's onto my computer in 8 hours of time without any further user intervention.
It might however require you to start the script twice if the internet connection isn't optimal.

If the 5 seconds isn't enough for the complete page to load, change the following line:
var timeBeforeFirstGame = 5000;
Increase the 5000 to the number of milliseconds you want to wait for the page to load.

Comment: Uhh, where's the script?

Comment: Someone removed the link.. Don't know why. Search for "InstallAllSteamGames" on userscripts.org if they remove it again.

Comment: According to the edit history, nobody removed the link from your answer.  It doesn't look like you included it in the first place.

Comment: mirror: http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/171425.html

Answer (score 1):

I've Found out how to make this work. First get greasemonkey addon for Firefox then use the script that was linked above :http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/171425 and follow steps 1-3.

now i was confused because when i went to my profile page it doesn't say my name it just has a bunch of numbers i think this is steams new way **SO**. what you have to do is go into greasemonkey>manage user scripts>installallsteamgamesscript>options> then on the user settings> included pages>add and then add a url like this http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/*/games?tab=all#installall except replace the * with the numbers after profiles/ that you see when you go to your profile on steam. after you've added that to the included section put that into your browser and wait a few seconds for it to start up. Worked for me :D

Answer (score 0):

`steam://subscriptioninstall/id1/id2/...` Opens a dialog box with a checklist of the games specified allowing you to install them all at once.

Comment: Doesn't do anything on my end. I do have Steam running currently.

Comment: @kotekzot Don't do the /id1 but replace that with your game id. Just like the anwser from TrewTzu.

Comment: @Lyrion compiling a list of your games' IDs seems like a lot of work. Interesting option, though.

Comment: @kotekzot Yep i agree, but if you could automate the process then it would be alot easyer.

Comment: I wonder if anything bad would happen if you make this URL with every Steam ID for every Steam game?