# Is there a way to get more than one thing to download at once?

Tags: steam

I bought the Telltale Complete Pack from Steam, and while I realize downloading it all at once would probably make my computer implode and pretty much kill my internet forever, I want to at least download more than one thing at a time (or at the very least, make sure it downloads each game I bought, in sequence or something).

Is there a way to do that in Steam?

Comment: Have you tried taking a look at a traffic control/monitoring program such as: http://www.seriousbit.com/netbalancer/ or http://www.netlimiter.com/ -- Alternatively, you can QoS TCP ports 27000-27050 down to low(est) priority.

Comment: Possibly related to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/31956/8366, which is also related to another downloading question. And what's odd is that I thought Steam automatically downloads as many games at once as it can ... at least that's what I thought when I've purchased, say, a Humble Bundle.

Comment: @Krazer I have no idea what that means.

Comment: @DaveDuPlantis usually it does, but since I seemingly had download issues (it kept telling me it wasn't connected to the network, even though I was online the whole time), most of the games aborted downloads.

Comment: @AshleyNunn I never had problems downloading several games at once... when Steam felt like it. To my best of knowledge there is no way to control Steam's downloads in a precise manner, and I suspect what you are experiencing is one of the many lovely phenomena that appear when Steam is under load (which usually happens during massive sales).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, for all intents and purposes, you can't. Steam will automagically decide what is best for your connection and the Steam servers and will act accordingly.

My personal experience is that during times that Steam is relatively quiet, it will download a few games at a time, at reasonable speeds. Otherwise, it only downloads one game at a time. My own connection settings do not seem to have any influence on this.