# Why can't I download an already purchased game on steam to my other pc? (VIA STEAM)

Tags: steam

So I have a new PC. I downloaded the Steam app. Some days ago I just got a game(Ace of Spades) and I wanna use it on this PC. When I click play now on its Steam page it doesn't start the download, but it starts a window named: Steam - Update News. This window is almost empty it only has the copyright things at the bottom.

My ideas:

- I just reset my password. Maybe this is the problem.
- Steam is just buggy for me.
- Or it is a problem with my computer or my account.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the game from your library, rather than from the Steam store?

Comment: If you still have the old PC, you might look at [this related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12695/how-do-i-move-steam-games-to-a-new-computer-without-re-downloading-them?rq=1) on how to transfer games without the need for downloading.

Comment: You most probably have a connectivity issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Steam - Update news is a general pop-up window that comes up whenever steam has some offers or news for you in general. Like @ahillier88 pointed out, try downloading from your library instead, i am sure it will work.

Hope this helps! Happy Gamin'!