# How do I transfer Borderlands 2 game save files onto another account or computer?

Tags: steam, borderlands-2, macos

How do I move the game save from my friend's Steam account onto my account? This is on the same computer.

Also, how do I put game save files on a hard drive and move it onto a different computer?

The game I'm trying to do this on is Borderlands 2 on Mac OS X Version 10.7.5.

Comment: See this http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12695/how-do-i-move-steam-games-to-a-new-computer-without-re-downloading-them?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Borderlands 2 savegames are stored in

**Windows:**

`C:\Users\[user]\Documents\My Games\Borderlands 2\WillowGame\SaveData\__numerical_id__\`

**Mac:**

`~/Library/Application Support/Borderlands 2/WillowGame/SaveData/__numerical_id__/`

Just copy the folder from one Computer to the other.

Answer (score 0):

For mac user that got the game from app store, here we go:

Go to `terminal` and paste this command:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

then go to user:

admin user (you)  -> library -> containers -> com.aspyr.borderlands2.appstore -> data -> library -> application support -> borderlands 2 -> willowgame -> save data

Done.

Answer (score 0):

OK, apparently the previous messages didn't take into account permissions or SteamPlay cloud sync.

First thing you want to do is turn off SteamPlay cloud sync on your account (the one you are copying to)
Then you need to copy the game files (mentioned in the other answers). If you don't have read permission, from your account make sure to set that up on your friend's account.

After that you may need to change the permissions on the new save.  (I'm not sure if finder's copy routine defaults to parent directory permissions or source directory permissions.  It's best to check and change them if necessary.)

Finally you need to open the game with with the new save file, quit it, turn back on SteamPlay cloud sync, and then open and close the game again to sync the saves to SteamPlay.