# Help with Steam game files

Tags: steam, dota-2

I got and installed Steam a few months ago in my system drive. And then I got a backup of Dota 2 and installed it. It was fine till a month ago before my lap top got broken.
With passing problems and finally getting my new pc and recovering a small amount of my past laptop data I found out that my Steam client has been removed.

Now the problem is that I have my Dota game folder (it's not the backup file) but I don't have my Steam client and I should reinstall it.
After that am I gonna be able to play Dota again? Or should I download it from the beginning?
It may not be an important thing in developed countries but in mine it is.
12GB is a huge amount for downloading!

Comment: You have your old dota 2 folder backed up? If so, you shouldn't have to redownload it.

Comment: No bro....i have my installed game folder....dota 2 beta folder but not the backed up data...

Comment: What I mean is that the folder contents the game files?

Comment: Yes....cause i didnt instal it in my steam folder...its in my other drive. But contains the full data of the game.

Comment: Then read the answers of this [question, it should answer yours](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12695/how-do-i-move-steam-games-to-a-new-computer-without-re-downloading-them). Basically, install steam and have steam install dota in your current folder, it shouldn't download much before being playable. You might need to move your current folder into your new library or create a library to match your current folder.

Comment: @uncledaryl, do you still have the DoTA 2 manifest file (`appmanifest_570.acf` and `appmanifest_316570.acf` files in your `[Steam Install]/SteamApps/...` folder?)

Comment: Also @JonathanDrapeau, don't you think the answers are a little outdated? (We don't use `.gcf` files anymore; `.vpk`s are the replacements and games are now stored in folders...)

Comment: @aytimothy true then this [answer is more up to date](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/187976/61395).

Comment: Tnx for the answer....yes i have the full game with its contents....i installed my dota out of steam folder it has its own library but as i said i dont have the client i have the raw library!!

Comment: @Jonathan That's my answer. xD | Also, that's about moving. He's asking about Steam detecting an already-downloaded but not-in-the-Steam-library-game.

Comment: @uncledaryl then reinstall steam and have it reinstall all the games into your old library. You should only download the needed updates.

Comment: @aytimothy it is basically the same idea, he has the files, he just needs Steam to recognize them, same as moving them from one place to another, except the move part as they are moved already.

Comment: @Jonathan true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a copy of the manifest files (`appmanifest_570.acf` and `appmanifest_316570.acf`), simply copy them into the same Steam Library folder your DoTA 2 installation is located in, and restart Steam.

*So, if your Steam Library folder was the default; `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\...`, then copy those files there.*

---

However, if you do not have your manifest files, just leave your DoTA 2 folder (make sure it is in your Steam Library folder; ie. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\dota 2 beta\...`) where it is, and attempt to reinstall DoTA 2 **in the same place it is already installed**.

**Steam will automatically scan the files (see what's still valid and what needs updating) and download any updates as needed... And create new manifest files too.**
It's just like running a "Verify Game Cache", except not through that menu.

Comment: Tnx for your helps and your time...i think the main answer is to copy common file that includes dota 2 to my steam library!!