# Steam on another PC after uninstall

Tags: steam, pc

I'm going to have a new PC and I will uninstall everything on my old PC (reset to factory setting). I need to know if this affect my Steam installation on the new PC in any way. Will I still have my games on my new PC? I know they'll not be installed but will they still be in my library?

Comment: This might be useful for you: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12695/how-do-i-move-steam-games-to-a-new-computer-without-re-downloading-them

Answer (score 3):

Installing or uninstalling a steam game on one computer does not affect the installation of the game on another computer and does not remove the game from your library (this can be done, but really only on purpose).

I.e. you can have Games A,B,C installed on computer 1, and A,D,E,F on computer 2. If you now uninstall A,B,C on computer 1, A,D,E,F will still be installed on 2. Similarly, installing G on 2 will not cause steam to install the game on 1.