# What will happen if I resumed a Steam download on another PC?

Tags: steam

If I downloaded say 30% of a game on a PC then went to another PC, will it be able to resume the download? and will it work?

I have an internet limit which is 100 GB and I want to download Grand Theft Auto 5. I have 20 GB left until tomorrow, but don't have the PC on which I will play the game, so can I download 30% of it now and when I get my PC can I resume the download?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I move Steam games to a new computer without re-downloading them?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12695/how-do-i-move-steam-games-to-a-new-computer-without-re-downloading-them)

Comment: No the downloaded files will be installed on the computer that its downloaded to. Downloading does not work the way you think.

Comment: I know that you can move entire games across like in the question @DanmakuGrazer links, so theoretically you *could* potentially move the partially-downloaded game across to the new PC, then start Steam and 'resume' the download. However I have no idea if this will work or how Steam copes with a game in a partially-downloaded state.

Comment: It works with most games. Steam is able to identify the current state of your download by verifying the game files. It will still eat some traffic, but not nearly as much as starting a fresh download. Partially downloaded single files might not be able to be resumed and their download will be restarted.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

This is simply not a feature in Steam.
It does not allow you to download a specific part of the gamefiles.
Should you start a new download on another computer, it will open the installation wizard and you will have to download the entire game from the beginning (for that computer).