# Continuing downloads on Steam

Tags: steam

I purchased Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege a while ago and I was waiting for a good time to download it so I wouldn't go over my monthly quota.
So earlier this month I started downloading it but had to stop after 35GB, with about 40GB remaining.
Then I finished my new build (Ryzen R7 2700X) and started using it. Unfortunately the 35 GB of download was on my old PC.
I don't want to have to restart the download. How do I transfer the downloaded files so that when I start to download it again on my new PC it picks up where It left off?

Comment: Perhaps an X -> Y problem. Check if your ISP has a single-day "unlimited data" option. I regularly use this when travelling and wanting to download a game without affecting my monthy data quota. It's 5€ per day for the German Telekom provider.

Comment: I'm sorry  but I don't understand why this would be an issue if I'm downloading it in pieces on different days. I can see it being an issue if I was downloading the whole 75 GB in one sitting.

Comment: Have you tried just finishing the download on the old PC, then transferring the game? That might just be easier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I move Steam games to a new computer without re-downloading them?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12695/how-do-i-move-steam-games-to-a-new-computer-without-re-downloading-them)

Comment: I would say that this question is NOT a dupe of that. Here OP is in the process of downloading the game and is stored differently than a complete Steam game.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a folder called `Program Files/Steam/Steamapps/downloading` which contains files currently being downloaded. You'll need to start the download on your new computer, pause it, get the files off your old computer (from `/downloading`), navigate to `Program Files/Steam/Steamapps/common/Rainbow Six Siege`, and put the files (from the old computer) there (the new computer).

Verify the integrity of your game files in the game's `Properties > Local Files` window. Then, continue your download. Steam should now pick up from where you left off on the last computer.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I'll try that. I was putting the files from Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/downloading/359550 on my old computer to the  same folder on the new one. I guess that was my mistake. I'll update you after trying.

Comment: Yeah, they won't contain anything yet to prevent corruption.

Comment: OK. Copied the files and validated. It's now Pre-allocating.

Comment: No go. It started the download from the beginning again. I guess I'll have to start again. I've done this before lots of times but only after the game was finished installing. i.e. copying the files from ...steamapps/common/Game Files to other drives. I've never done it in the middle of a download.

Comment: No go. It started the download from the beginning again. I guess I'll have to start again. I've done this before lots of times but only after the game was finished  I've never done it in the middle of a download. I'm also in the process of downloading Wolfenstein II: The New Colossus. I can pause that one and it picks up where it left off. But, there are no files yet in the steamapps/common/Wolfenstein.II.The.New.Colossus folder so I'm a little confused as to why you had me place the "downloading" files from my old PC to the steamapps/Tom Clancy's Rainbox Six Siege folder.

Comment: The other thing I don't understand is when I start downloading a game, after Pre-allocating and the download has actually started, the steamapps/Game ID folder contains or appears to contain the full amount of files (bytes used) as if it was finished downloading. I know it's my ignorance but why is that? Is that the "pre-allocating" amount?

Comment: I meant the /steamapps/downloading/Game ID folder

Comment: "there are no files yet": the folder is empty because none of the files have been moved into it yet. They're all in the /downloading folder. . . 
"Pre-allocating": that's exactly what it's doing yes.
. . .
Confusing that this didn't work. The downloading files were there, yes?